# Tkinter doesn't work with .py to .exe conversions

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-10, py2exe, pyinstaller

I have been working on a Python script which requires me to make a window for it and process the data entered by the user in text boxes and with button interaction. For this I decided to use Tkinter...

I have had no problems at all so far, and limited my programming so far so I wouldn't use modules not included in the 2.7 python library, because I anticipated those would be a problem when trying to compile Python code into an executable file.

Turns out my issues were actually with a module included in the Python library: Tkinter.

I have tried both `py2exe` and `pyinstaller`, and both gave me the same kind of mistakes:

> Import errors, "no such module as Tkinter".

I have tried everything I could come up with: I have used `--onefile`, I have added hidden imports on the `.spec` file and then used `pyinstaller` on it... All of these tries produced slightly different errors, but all of them revolved around not being able to import Tkinter.

I would be really thankful if someone has had a similar experience with `pyinstaller` or `py2exe`. I know there are similar topics to this one on the forum but I tried everything suggested that would apply to me on those other topics but I couldn't sort this problem out.

My complete tkinter code is:

```
import Tkinter 
from Tkinter import * 

master = Tk() 
master.title('App') 
canvas = Canvas(master, width = 666, height = 400) 
canvas.pack() 
imagem = PhotoImage(file='C:\\ProjetoFCTUNL\\a0VRm.gif') 
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor = NW, image= imagem) 

def callback(): 
    global livro 
    livro = e1.get() +'.txt' 

def callback2(): 
    global livro2 
    livro2 =e2.get() +'.txt' 
    global livro 
    livro = e1.get() +'.txt' 

v = StringVar() 
v2 = StringVar() 
e1 = Entry(master, textvariable=v) 
e1.pack() 
e2 = Entry(master, textvariable=v2) 
e2.pack()
```

The error I usually get is a window saying "failed to execute script" and if I open it via CMD it just says "failed to import tkinter"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for us to best assist, it would be great if you can provide part of your code that is resulting in the difficulty you're facing. Additionally, any detailed information regarding the error is beneficial as well (i.e. relevant parts of the error log).

Comment: import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
master = Tk()
master.title('App')
canvas = Canvas(master, width = 666, height = 400)
canvas.pack()
imagem = PhotoImage(file='C:\\ProjetoFCTUNL\\a0VRm.gif')
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor = NW, image= imagem)

def callback():
    global livro
    livro = e1.get() +'.txt'
def callback2():
    global livro2
    livro2 =e2.get() +'.txt'
    global livro
    livro = e1.get() +'.txt'    
v = StringVar()
v2 = StringVar()
e1 = Entry(master, textvariable=v)
e1.pack()
e2 = Entry(master, textvariable=v2)
e2.pack()

This all of my tkinter code

Comment: The error I usually get is a window saying "failed to execute script" and if I open it via CMD it just says "failed to import tkinter"

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes for me works just 'import tkinter' and not 'import Tkinter' based on different python versions

Comment: You can be more specific - `Tkinter` is for Py2 and `tkinter` is for Py3

Comment: your answers sounds a bit generic, can you add some more details?